# Xfce4: new Evince windows larger than screen

Tags: xfce, window-manager, evince

I'm running Xfce 4.12 (on openSUSE). Most of the time when a new Evince window is opened, it has a convenient width (3/4 of the screen width or so), but it's way too high, like > 120% or so of the screen height, such that the bottom of the window is way off-screen. Thus I always have to resize it by hand, which is super-tedious (*).

**Is there any way to open new Evince windows always at the same size in the same place, or at the very least fully on-screen?**

BTW: I have shortcuts in place to maximize the window, as well as tile it to one half of the screen, but for PDFs, that usually not what I want.

*(*) I have to move the window away from the top of the screen, resize it from the top, move it up, repeat until the full window is fully on the screen, move it back up, and resize it toward the bottom until it reaches the bottom of the screen.*

Note: It's my office computer, so solutions not requiring admin rights are strongly preferred.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may not work out because of the admin restriction.

I am using Xfce on Debian 9. I gave up on Evince. I had the same issues. Instead I use `qpdfview` and also this script that I named `chromium-pdf-img-viewer`:

```
#!/bin/bash

fname=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/ /\%20/g')
chromium --app="file://$fname"
```

You would need to install `chromium` first. You can mark it as executable and put the script in `~/bin`. In Thunar you can right click on the pdf file or jpg, etc. Then go to Properties > Open With > Other Application > Use a custom command. Then you can add the script. It does not work for file names with an accent on them. For it to work on CLI it is a little different. I'm glad to post that if interested.

This script below will maximize Evince on launch. You would name it `evince` and put it in `~/bin`. It requires the install of `wmctrl` and `xdotool`.

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/evince "$@" & 
sleep 2
window_id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
wmctrl -ir $window_id -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
```

Comment: @flotzilla I misread your question "at the very least fully on-screen?" This would be possible through the use of `xdotool` and `wmtcrl`. I already have  a script for resizing windows with the keyboard. You could assign keyboard shortcuts for that if you'd like for me to post it. However, you could integrate the above two programs into a script to tile the evince window to your screen height. I could write a script for that if so desired, but it may take a while to get back with that.